# Qual a melhor maneira de armazenar múltiplas categorias de um mesmo produto?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Olá, eu tenho uma tabela chamada `'produtos_dados'` aonde armazeno algumas informações de produtos:

| ID_Produto | Nome_Produto | Descricao_Produto |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Leite Condensado | Um produto legal... |
| 2 | Chocolate Amargo | Um doce muito bom.. |

Junto a esta tabela, eu tenho uma outra tabela chamada `'categorias'`:

| ID_Categoria | Nome_Categoria | Descricao_Categoria |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sem-Glúten | ................... |
| 2 | Vegano | ................... |

O que acontece, é que os produtos podem pertencer a mais de uma categoria, como por exemplo, o produto chocolate amargo, ele pode estar tanto na categoria de Sem-Glúten como também na de Vegano.

Sabendo disso, como eu posso fazer esse link entre as tabelas?

1. Será que se eu criar uma coluna na tabela `'produtos_dados'` chamada de `'IDs_Categorias'` e inserir como dado `'1, 2'` seria o certo?
2. Ou será que o mais correto seria criar uma nova tabela chamada `'produtos_categorias'` (`ID_ProdutoCategoria`, `ID_Produto`, `ID_Categoria`) e ir linkando essas duas tabelas?

Comment: *" os produtos podem pertencer a mais de uma categoria"* isso é uma relação `n:n` ou `n:m`, ou ainda `muitos para muitos`, logo precisa de uma tabela de relação entre produto x categoria, algo que tenha na chave primária "(id_product, id_categoria)", ou seja, a sua segunda sugestão é que melhor se aplica ai

Comment: Produto-|----<produto_categoria>---|-categoria

Answer (score -2):

Exatamente como vc disse, a melhor forma de vc fazer esse relacionamento n:n seria criando uma tabela que guardará esse link entre o produto e suas categorias, essa seria a boa prática.

[Acredito que esse seja seu cenário](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESSmP.png)